# How to LDAP query without knowing exact OU

Tags: vbscript, ldap

```
Set objDomain = GetObject("WinNT://abc.local")

For each objDomainItem in objDomain

    if objDomainItem.Class = "User" then

        'WScript.echo "Name: " & objDomainItem.Name + " : Full Name: " + objDomainItem.FullName

        Set objUser = Nothing
        err.clear

        Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://cn=" & objDomainItem.FullName & ",OU=IS, OU=Users, OU=ABC Company, DC=ABC, dc=local")

        if err.number = 0 then
            wscript.echo "distinguishedName: " & objUser.distinguishedName
        end if


    end if


Next
```

Right now, this works fine to list all users in the IS department (OU=IS).  But when I take out "OU=IS" to list all users in all departments, it returns nothing; no user objects at all.  The only way it will return the user object for the given fullName is if I also specify the OU that that user is contained in; but I do not have the OU to supply it.

Our AD structure is

```
ABC Company --> Users --> IS
ABC Company --> Users --> FINANCE
ABC Company --> Users --> Management
ABC Company --> Users --> Flight Operations
etc etc etc
```

I want to use the code above to enumerate all users from the "Users" level, down through ALL departments, but again, as soon as I remove "OU=IS", it returns nothing.

Any help?

Comment: Ansgar's answer, below got me around the problem nicely.  His ADQuery class got me what I wanted.  But it doesn't really answer THIS question, so I am unsure how to call it.  Do I leave it unanswered and just heap praises on Ansgar?  Or do I mark his answer as correct, even though it doesn't really address the problem as presented?

Comment: I updated my answer. The modified code should return all user objects in the subtree below `OU=Users,OU=ABC Company,DC=ABC,DC=local`. Please check if this works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a query with scope `Subtree` using an `ADODB.Connection` and an `ADODB.Command` object:

```
base  = "<LDAP://OU=Users,OU=ABC Company,DC=ABC,DC=local>"
fltr  = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=Person))"
attr  = "distinguishedName,sAMAccountName"
scope = "subtree"

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cn.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
cn.Open "Active Directory Provider"

Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = cn
cmd.CommandText = base & ";" & fltr & ";" & attr & ";" & scope

Set rs = cmd.Execute
Do Until rs.EOF
  WScript.Echo rs.Fields("distinguishedName").Value
  WScript.Echo rs.Fields("sAMAccountName").Value
  rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

Add other attributes to `attr` as required (the variable contains a list of attribute names as a comma-separated string).

Since these queries require the same boilerplate code every time, I got fed up with writing it over and over again some time ago and wrapped it in a custom class ([`ADQuery`](http://www.planetcobalt.net/sdb/adquery.shtml)) to simplify its usage:

```
'<-- paste or include class code here

Set qry = New ADQuery
qry.SearchBase = "OU=Users,OU=ABC Company,DC=ABC,DC=local"
qry.Attributes = Array("distinguishedName", "sAMAccountName")

Set rs = qry.Execute
Do Until rs.EOF
  WScript.Echo rs.Fields("distinguishedName").Value
  WScript.Echo rs.Fields("sAMAccountName").Value
  rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

Comment: What a coincidence.  I just downloaded your ADQuery just this past Friday.  Was going to crack it open and try it if I didn't solve this problem.  Small world.  ;-)